# Could I ask where i mistook in using riccati matrix equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential-topology, nonlinear-system

I was trying to solve
$$ \dot{x}=ax^2+bxy\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
$$ \dot{y}=cy^2+dxy \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
According to riccati equation's initial showing
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \begin{bmatrix}
M(t) \\
N(t)
\end{bmatrix} \right)
 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-A&-B\\
C&D 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
M(t) \\
N(t)
\end{bmatrix}
where  \ P=N(t)M(t)^{-1}, then \ \dot{P}= PBP + AP + PD + C
\tag{3}\label{eq3}$$
To match \eqref{eq1} and \eqref{eq2} with the form \eqref{eq3}, I applied small change as follows,
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix} \right)
 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x& 0\\
0& y 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a& b\\
c& d 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{4}\label{eq4}$$
and changed to the following
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \begin{bmatrix}
x& 0\\
0& y 
\end{bmatrix} \right)\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x& 0\\
0& y 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a& b\\
c& d 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x& 0\\
0& y 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}\tag{5}\label{eq5}
$$
This form looks similar to \eqref{eq3}
$$
\dot{P}=PBP \tag{6}\label{eq6}
$$
Therefore, I transformed \eqref{eq6} to \eqref{eq3}
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left( \begin{bmatrix}
M(t) \\
N(t)
\end{bmatrix} \right)
 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-B\\
0&0 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
M(t) \\
N(t)
\end{bmatrix}
where  \ X=N(t)M(t)^{-1} \tag{7}\label{eq7} \ and \ \, H=\begin{bmatrix}
0&-B\\
0&0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Unlike riccati matrix equation, H in \eqref{eq7} is singular. So, directly applying riccati method seems not possible. Therefore, I chose exponential matrix of H.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
M(t) \\
N(t)
\end{bmatrix} = e^{Ht}
\begin{bmatrix}
M(0) \\
N(0)
\end{bmatrix}
, where \ X=N(t)M(t)^{-1} \tag{8}\label{eq8}
$$
and I multiply $$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ to  X in \eqref{eq8}.$$

Ok, I tested the result at the 1 dimension such as $$\dot{x} =ax^2$$
I showed well.

However, when I applied it into 2 dimensional problem that I wondered such as \eqref{eq1}  \eqref{eq2}, It does not satisfied.

Could you let me know why and which part of my assumption was incorrect?

Such as $$\begin{bmatrix}
x& 0\\
0& y 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$$
or etc.

Comment: I'd say that your reasoning would be acceptable if you could guarantee that the matrix $P$ stays diagonal during integration. As that is not the case, your last formula is not true, the off-diagonal entries are not zero. You could try to solve for $h$ in $y(t)=x(t)h(x(t))$.

Comment: @ Lutz Lehmann  You mean, when moving from (4) to (5), because the left hand side was not have off-diagonal properties while the right hand side has one, that is the point my approach was wrong. right?

Comment: More like from (5) to (6), as (5) is still the original system. In (6) this is augmented to a system with 4 components that is not hierarchically coupled. Meaning the off-diagonal entries of $P$ contribute to the equations for the diagonal entries.